# DesktopAppConverter doesn't work

Tags: uwp, desktop-bridge

See the following screenshot:

[image]

I don't know why. My environment should be correct.

[image]

Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you installed .NET 4.6.2 https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=53321?

Comment: Which app did you use for converter?

Comment: I didn't event start to convert my desktop app.

Comment: Stefano Balzarotti I have installed .NET 4.6.2

Comment: Any suggestions would be appreciative :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you included the `CMD PS C:\>` part of the setup command from the docs.

As a result, **this created a file named `DesktopAppConverter.exe` in his current directory (system32)**. So when run a DAC command, it tries to run the file he created in the current directory instead of the correct DAC entry point.

The solution is to **delete** the DesktopAppConverter.exe file in the current folder:

`del DesktopAppConverter.exe`

We are updating the docs to get rid of the `CMD PS C:\>` to avoid such cases.

Answer (score 0):

Ok. I found the solution.

I type in the wrong command in PS. But this does not mean that we have a crashed environment.

To overcome this error and setup the right environment please follow my steps below:

1. Download required files from this site:  https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=54283

We need the DesktopAppConverter.zip and BaseImage-xxxx.wim

2. Exact the above zip to a folder and also move your above BaseImage to that folder
3. Open a PowerShell script with Admin privilege
4. CD YourExtractedFolderPath
5. Directly type this command: Set-ExecutionPolicy bypass

   Type yes in the above command.
6. Directly type this command: .\DesktopAppConverter.ps1 -Setup -BaseImage .\BaseImage-1XXXX.wim -Verbose

In this way you will get the result about the container feature has been enabled and you will be able to restart your machine to install the "container" feature. This problem is also related to that we are not familiar with PS command and typed something like PS C:> in your command, which will cause the error I mentioned.

Comment: Using ps script is also working, for your original question, please also see my answer:)